# Map Values to Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I have a data frame with a 'State' column denoting each record's State. I want to map the States to regions and I've created a dict:

```
     di = {'Mideast': ['DL', 'DC', 'MD', 'NJ', 'NY', 'PA'], 'West': [ . . , . .], . . . }
```

which is built using variables such as

```
    Mideast = ['DL', 'DC', 'MD', 'NJ', 'NY', 'PA']
```

Why a naive method like this does not work?

```
    for i in df_test['State']:
        if i in Mideast: i = 'Mideast';
```

a sample value from the df:

```
State   Area Code    Phone    Intl Calls  Intl Charge  CustServ Calls   Churn?
KS       415        382-4657       3          2.7           1           False.
```

I've searched online for possible solutions. I am trying them, but it bugs me that the method above seems so out of bounds that nobody even mentioned it. I am apparently not understanding something very fundamental, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

di = {'Wonderful spam': ['Spam', 'Egg', 'Sausage'], 'Lovely spam': ['Baked beans', 'Tomato']}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(["Tomato"],columns=["State"])

for i, x in enumerate(df_test['State']):
    for group, names in di.items():
        if x in names:
            df_test['State'][i] = group

print(df_test)
```

Output:

```
         State
0  Lovely spam
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample value for `df`?

Comment: Yes. Each record has 20 variables + 1 predicted variable Churn?, but I removed some of them for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
di = {'Mideast': ['DL', 'DC', 'MD', 'NJ', 'NY', 'PA'], 'West': [ . . , . .], . . . }

mod_dict = {v:k for k,val in di.iteritems() for v in val}

for k,v in mod_dict.iteritems():

    df_test.loc[df_test['States'] = k, 'States'] = v
```

I have converted initial `di` to `mod_dict` of form

```
 'DC': 'Mideast',
 'DL': 'Mideast',
 'MD': 'Mideast',
 'NJ': 'Mideast',
 'NY': 'Mideast',
 'PA': 'Mideast'}
 .
 . 
 .
```

Now I am looking for each country code in `df` and if found replacing it with the value of that code with region name.

Hope this helps.